# How to set a default date when extending DateRangeItem FieldType plugin

Tags: 8, datetime

I created a new field type plugin that extends DateRangeItem. My plugin only adds some more settings. I also created an own widget that extends DateRangeWidgetBase. My formElement function looks like this:

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);
  $time_type = 'time';
  $time_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_time')->getPattern();

  $element['value'] += [
    '#date_date_format' => 'none',
    '#date_date_element' => 'none',
    '#date_date_callbacks' => [],
    '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
    '#date_time_element' => $time_type,
    '#date_time_callbacks' => [],
    '#default_value' => $this->createDefaultValue($items[$delta]->start_date, $element['value']['#date_timezone'])
  ];

  ...
}

protected function createDefaultValue($date, $timezone) {
  $date = parent::createDefaultValue($date, $timezone);
  $date->setDate(2018, 01, 01);
  return $date;
}
```

I only want the user to be able to enter a time value, but no date value. This works.

My problem is that when saving the field value it is always stored with the date of the current day - this seems to be the default value. (The time is set correctly according to what the user enters). I want to set a different fixed date instead.

So I'm overwriting createDefaultValue as shown above, but without any effect.

If I comment out the two lines

```
//'#date_date_format' => 'none',
//'#date_date_element' => 'none',
```

my new default value is shown and also saved correctly. But if set the two lines to not show the date, my default value is ignored.

How can I set a default value and not show the date (only time)?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Are you extending the entire daterange field (item, widgets, and formatters), or just the widgets?

Comment: The entire daterange field (item, widget and formatter). But my extension of the field item only adds one property and does nothing else.

Comment: Weird.  I think this may be a side effect from the form element widget (which confusingly is also called Datetime).  You may need to start setting breakpoints to see what is going on.

Comment: Just want to expand a little bit on my last comment.  The Datetime stuff is, uh, pretty complicated.  What I suspect is happening, is that a DDT/DTP/DateTime object is being created and only given the time.  In that case, it will pull the current date.  Unfortunately, there is a decent amount of string<->object stuff going on.  You need to start from the widget form, and trace it through the form element, and then into the massageFormValues to see where the breakage is happening.

Comment: I can't find the reason. I found a workaround and I'm using hook_entity_presave to change the value of the field. But it's a very strange behaviour, also the documentation is far from complete regarding daterange fields (e.g. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/datetime-range/how-to-use-datetime-range-in-a-custom-entity)